# Firefox 49 debugger js not stop at some breakpoints, with $(window).on(scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox

Problem is:

```
$(window).on('scroll', function() {
    var currentTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    //check if user is scrolling up
    console.log('previousTop is ', this.previous);
    if (currentTop < this.previous) {
        //if scrolling up...
        if (currentTop > 0 && $('.navbar-custom').hasClass('is-fixed')) {
            $('.navbar-custom').addClass('is-visible');
        } else {
            $('.navbar-custom').removeClass('is-visible is-fixed');
        }
    } else if (currentTop > this.previous) {
        //if scrolling down...
        $('.navbar-custom').removeClass('is-visible');
        if (currentTop > headerHeight && !$('.navbar-custom').hasClass('is-fixed')) $('.navbar-custom').addClass('is-fixed');
    }
    this.previous = currentTop;
});
```

I want to stop at console.log line, and firefox stop this line, but this line has been executed many times.

The web pager is: https://blackrockdigital.github.io/startbootstrap-clean-blog/

More: I'm a fresh man to js. If this is a simple problem, I'm sorry, please help me. and chrome is fine.

Comment: I've had issues with putting breakpoints inside an event handler - and 'scroll' gets hit a lot even with a small movement

Comment: I know that it should hit many times. but Why not hit the firest time in firefox?